# execute same cronJob with multiple and dynamic dates

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

please i need help with this :

i'm developing an application where the user select multiple dates from a calendar in the frontend and those dates are sent to the spring-boot backend and stored into a database.
On those exact dates i need to execute a cronjob (let's say send an email).

-First of all :  i have convert each date to a cron schedule expressions
for example the user choose 3 dates and the result is a list of 3 cron expressions as below :

*[ "0 0 8-10 * * *"  **,** "* 30 16 * * *"  **,**  "* * 9 * * *"* ]*

**how can i dynamically execute the same job 3 times with the 3 differents cron expressions ??? :**

```
`@Scheduled(cron = "cron[0]" & "cron[1]" & "cron[2]") // <--- this is what i need 
  private void sendEmail() {

  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) for dynamic scheduling based on data. Like this:

```java
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;

private final TaskScheduler executor;

String[] cronList = { "0 0 8-10 * * " , " 30 16 * * " , " * 9 * * " };

for (String cron: cronList) {
    executor.schedule(() -> {
        // do your job here
    }, new CronTrigger(cron));
}
```

In your case, you don't need to convert Date to a cron expression. You can specify [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) or [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) as a parameter. Read this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,java.time.Instant)).

**For Example:**

I want to run the task one minute after now. In this case, I use LocalDateTime and convert to Instant.

```java
LocalDateTime oneMinuteAfter = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(1);

executor.schedule(() => {}, oneMinuteAfter.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: Done, i really appreciate the help! , you said that there is no need to convert date to cron expresssion , but it seems , this is only workig with cron expression ! can you show me an example ?

Comment: Just pass your Date or Instant variable to the second parameter. I edited the answer to add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations work with constant expressions.
So You can not put dynamic expressions inside an annotation.
The compiler should show you an error, which explains exactly this.

You could create one method, which is executed every minute (with @Scheduled annotation). This method calls database and sends Email to users inside your database, which fit to current timeslot.

More details about @Scheduled in my German blog: 
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2021/03/spring-cronjobs.html

Comment: i know about annotation and constant expressions and i've thinked about that , but a cron executed every minute ? huh ? i think it's not an efficient way right ?  i have another crons working in background and maybe this will affect the flow :/

Comment: If the solution is effective or not depends on many aspects. Based on your question, I guess its hard to decide what is effective for an outsider.

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. Why do you think running something once a minute is too expensive?

Comment: because simply the amount of the data is very huge and i need to do some filter before i execute the job too :/  this is why i need an accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot schedule the cron job dynamically using the `@Scheduled` annotation. For this you need something like the `TaskScheduler` suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74890677/303598).

In case you have a static configuration such that you would like to schedule the same job with different cron expressions you can use the `@Schedule` annotation if you refactor the code slightly. For example,  you can extract the business logic to a separate method and then have three cron-annotated method delegate to that method, e.g.

```
private void sendEmail() {
    // lengthy method that does the actual work
}

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8-10 * *")
private void firstCron() {
    sendEmail();    
}

@Scheduled(cron = "30 16 * *")
private void secondCron() {
    sendEmail();        
}

@Scheduled(cron = "* 9 * *")
private void thirdCron() {
    sendEmail();        
}
```